# PATH not working on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Tags: macos, maven, terminal, zsh, wildfly

I want to configure maven and wildfly on my local mac computer. in terminal I use zsh shell. so, I input maven and wildfly home in .zshrc file as

```
MAVEN_HOME="/Users/myuser/Development/maven"
JBOSS_HOME="/Users/myuser/Development/wildfly"
```

and then

```
export PATH="$PATH:$JBOSS_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin"
```

but when I type maven command in terminal, it shows me this response

```
zsh: command not found: maven
```

then I put all 3 commands in .bashrc and .bash_profile files. but nothing. even after reboot. what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven command is `mvn`, not `maven` :)

Comment: I suppose you just have wrong paths. Call it like this: `/Users/myuser/Development/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh`. I bet you'll get the same message.

Comment: And of course you call `add-user.sh` and not `add-user`, right?